# Replication failover mechanism

Tags: 7, database

I am trying to set a master-slave environment for a Drupal 7 website. My concern is if the slave fails (with the current config) the site won't be accessible anymore.

So, how can an automatic mechanism detect this and set a flag (sick) so that for further requests that server won't be used anymore (something like what varnish does with backend probing)?

My current config does a Round Robin selection of the db connection to use for each select query.